# How long will oxygen last in a $3\times 3\times 3 $ meter room for one person?

Tags: estimation, air, gas, biology

Let's assume that the windows and doors are tightly closed.

- How can I calculate at what moment I will feel a lack of oxygen and my well-being will worsen?
- Can one person completely consume all the air before dying?
- How will the pressure in the room change then?

For example, movies show that astronauts have "*5 minutes of oxygen left*". How did they calculate it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about human physiology not physics